# PHP get a specific value from a foreach key

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to extract a value from a foreach loop:

```
$telephone1 = '1231315';
$telephone2 = '42342342';

$telephoneNums = array($telephone1,$telephone2);

foreach($telephoneNums as $telephoneNum){
    $telephoneNum = 't'.$telephoneNum;
}

echo $telephoneNum[0];
```

the value that is being output is `t`

If I do `echo $telephoneNum[1];` I get `4`

I'd like to get `t1231315` for `echo $telephoneNum[0]`

This is simple problem but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
<?php
$telephone1 = '1231315';
$telephone2 = '42342342';

$telephoneNums = array($telephone1,$telephone2);
$telephoneNum=array();
foreach($telephoneNums as $tele){
   $telephoneNum[] = 't'.$tele;
}
echo $telephoneNum[0];//t1231315
echo $telephoneNum[1];//t42342342
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Kindly could you please explain me the logic behind `$telephoneNum=array();` and `$telephoneNum[] = 't'.$tele;`, please?

Comment: If you write print_r($telephoneNums); means its will return Array ( [0] => 1231315 [1] => 42342342 ) and now create new array for storing new value after concat with "t" using "." operator.In foreach loop it return single value of array($telephoneNums) .So we need to store values new array($telephoneNum).If you write print_r($telephoneNum); it return Array ( [0] => t1231315 [1] => t42342342 ).

Comment: Just did. How do I go adding something like `$telephoneNum[] = trim($tele);` after `$telephoneNum[] = 't'.$tele;`. I tried using `$telephoneNum[] = trim($tele);` but then $telephone2  is taking the new value of telephone1

Comment: It's all written in the documentation of [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) and [array type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're just assigning a string and not pushing an array to assign:

```
$telephoneNum = 't'.$telephoneNum;
```

Use the array assignment:

```
$telephoneNum = array();
foreach($telephoneNums as $tel){
    $telephoneNum[] = 't'.$tel;
               // ^ this is important
}
echo $telephoneNum[0];
```

---

Sidenote:

In case you're wondering how `echo $telephoneNum[0];` is `t` and `echo $telephoneNum[1];` 4. Is because since the last iteration is the value `t42342342` overwriting `$telephoneNum` (the string) . And this is a behaviour of string access in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will need to do. There you are extracting the first character from a string which otherwise you should have extracted from an array:

```
$telephone1 = '1231315';
$telephone2 = '42342342';

$telephoneNums = array($telephone1,$telephone2);
$i = 0;
foreach($telephoneNums as $telephoneNum){
  $telephoneNums[$i] = 't'.$telephoneNum;
   $i++;
}

echo $telephoneNums[0]."\n";
echo $telephoneNums[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$telephone1 = '1231315';
$telephone2 = '42342342';

$telephoneNums = array($telephone1,$telephone2);
 $telephoneNumbers=array();
foreach($telephoneNums as $telephoneNum){
    $telephoneNumbers[] = 't'.$telephoneNum;//telephoneNumbers[] is an array
}

echo $telephoneNumbers[0];
```